# iOS7 UIToolbar crash

Tags: ipad, ios7, xcode5, uitoolbar

I have an iPad app that has been running fine until iOS7. This issue seems to be only on ipad 2nd gen models and earlier when iOS7 is installed. Anyway, I've been tearing my hair out trying to figure out where this error is coming from, but have had no luck. The console in xcode (5) reports the following error after I perform a logged in segue:

```
2013-11-18 11:17:31.768 MyApp[400:60b] *** -[UIToolbar backdropView:willChangeToGraphicsQuality:]: message sent to deallocated instance 0x18ec23e0
```

I can't lookup the address for more info (**image lookup -a 0x18ec23e0**) it just returns nothing.

In instruments running zombies, it reports that a  message was sent to a UIToolbar like so:

[image]

When I inspect the instance, I get the following:

[image]

How do I debug this? I have no idea where this call is being made and it seems dependent upon a physical deivce (doesn't happen on the iPad mini or ipad 3/4)

Comment: Is the iPad 2 retina?

Comment: Found this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19883238/nsconcretemaptable-backdropviewwillchangetographicsquality-error , do you have async tasks that takes some time to complete?

Comment: No, the iPads are not a retina display iPads (model's are MD328X/A and MC982X/A).

I do use AFNetworking to perform asyncronous REST web service calls, but the segue being performed is dependent on the task returning.

Comment: I just tried implementing a delayed trigger approach as seen in the suggested thread by juniperi, but this doesn't work regardless of length of timeout.

Comment: Did you fix this issue? I have the same problem right now.

Answer (score 0):

I was struggling with a very similar error, also with a UIToolbar, that I couldn’t figure out until a couple hours ago. I also had to use and try to understand the zombies’ instrument but without any luck.

What I did was to pay a close attention to the **call stack** that was presented when the **Exception Breakpoint** was activated as described in the following tutorial:

http://www.raywenderlich.com/10209/my-app-crashed-now-what-part-1

Even though the call stack didn’t point me to the exact code line, I noticed that the app was trying to add a UIToolbar to a ViewController. Turns out that what I was doing was creating a local UIToolbar inside of a method and adding it to the presented UIView. After have modified this behavior, I stopped having the annoying sudden crash. It was difficult for me to find the issue because looking at the code of the ViewController that caused the crash, there was no code that created or used a UIToolbar; however this VC included a custom view that did exactly that, as I explained before.

Have said all of this I recommend you to closely inspect the VC that generates the crash. If you need to create a UIToolbar programmatically I recommend you to declare it as a strong property to maintain the memory reference as long as needed.

I hope this helps you.

Answer (score 0):

I struggled with this for a while today. I had two storyboards, one for login/signup (set as the main storyboard for the project) and another with the rest of the application. The app delegate would detect if a user was logged in and instantiate the root view controller of the other storyboard. The root view controller of the login storyboard is a navigation controller and after after some investigation with instruments I realized there was a UIToolbar being instantiated from the nib. Opening up the storyboard file revealed an off-screen UIToolbar object in the root view controller. I deleted it and I'm not crashing any more.

I should also mention this crash was only occurring when I was using `MKMapView`.